# Data in Node Javascript Buffers coming in over stream from tcp connection is nonsense. Streaming gnss data from ntrip server with net module

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, gps

I'm using the `net` module for nodejs and connecting to my ntrip server.  I'm getting the ICY 200 OK response so all my creds are correct and then what I assume have to be the gnss corrections begin to come in as Javascript's Buffer type.  Pictured below.. A lot of these are bad characters so i tried different encoding methods and it all seems to be nonsense.  The end goal is to pass the data to my bluetooth gps receiver but if i pass it as is or as a string it does nothing. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks guys. I've tried all the modules i could find for parsing or translating rtk or gnss data, if you have any ideas, please let me know.  Im sorry I cant post any code as it has sensitive information but its a pretty basic setup just connecting to the server listening to data and logging the data with toString() function.[image]

Comment: Are you able to get a response from the receiver to see what the messages look like? It'd be a clue.

Comment: I get a response from the receiver but its a different format Im going to try an app i know works with it at some point and try sniffing the packet to see what theyre sending it but that doesnt help that i cant seem to get any discernible data from the stream in node right now